# App is Lagging/Hanging. Why?

Tags: android, performance, firebase

I made a simple profile in my android app and after uploading image to firebase storage my app is lagging in speed, the image uploaded is in KBs size and in my profile I am using a Navigation Drawer whose sliding animation is also hanging. I am unable to figure out whats going wrong.

Comment: Use [method tracing](https://developer.android.com/studio/profile/am-methodtrace.html) to try to see where your time is being spent.

Comment: Look at the size of image, if the resolution is too big the app will lag

Comment: I agree with CommonsWare. Use the Method Tracing and investigate your problem. If you locate the method causing issues, but you don't know how to fix it, then you can edit your post and upload the code causing the issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe your are using the Main thread for doing all the job. This is one reason for UI thread to hang(i.e) the app didn't hang but it waits for the main UI thread to complete its work.

Generally, the app hangs for this reason. As suggested by Commonsware track methods. Also, try using background threads instead of main thread.